# How to stop calling a function JS

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have two functions, one that is triggered by clicking the start button

```
function startGame() {
  setInterval(setCellPosition, 3000);
  setTimeGame = setTimeout(startGame, 2000);
  setTime();
};
```

and the second one, which will be called after clicking the reset button

```
function resetGame() {
  scoreBox.innerHTML = "0";
  timeBox.innerHTML = "60";
  liveBox.innerHTML = "3";
  clearTimeout(setTimeGame)
};
```

The `resetGame` function does not work. The values (score, time, live) are reset, but the `startGame` function does not stop. How to fix it? How do I stop the `startgame` functions?

Comment: I think it‘s because startGame is executed so often. I‘d try with calling the timeout outside the function so it only gets called once.

Comment: @sandrooco did not help :<

Comment: Well you already know how to stop the timeout. Use exactly the same approach for the interval.

Comment: Do you really want to create a new `setCellPosition` interval every two seconds? I think there should be at most a single active interval at any time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While you should rethink your algorythm as what you currently have is a bit complex for starting and stopping your game.

However, the idea behind this solution is to store all your [timeouts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/settimeout) and [interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) objects in an array. When a reset happens, you loop through every object and stop it.

Then you reset the array.

```
const sts = []; //all set timeouts and intervals

function startGame() {
  sts.push(setInterval(setCellPosition, 3000));
  sts.push(setTimeout(startGame, 2000));
  setTime();
};

function resetGame() {
  scoreBox.innerHTML = "0";
  timeBox.innerHTML = "60";
  liveBox.innerHTML = "3";
  sts.forEach(clearTimeout);
  sts.length = 0;
};
```

According to MDN:

> The returned timeoutID is a positive integer value which identifies
>   the timer created by the call to setTimeout(); this value can be
>   passed to clearTimeout() to cancel the timeout.
>
> It may be helpful to be aware that setTimeout() and setInterval()
>   share the same pool of IDs, and that clearTimeout() and
>   clearInterval() can technically be used interchangeably. For clarity,
>   however, you should try to always match them to avoid confusion when
>   maintaining your code.

Comment: You beat me to it, was going to say something similar.

Answer (score 1):

If you replace your setInterval with a `gameOver` flag and a `while` loop containing a `setTimeout`, like:

```
let gameOver = false;
function startGame() {
  while(gameOver == false){
    setTimeout(setCellPosition, 3000);
  }
   // Note: It seems strange that you're recursively calling `startGame` here
  setTimeGame = setTimeout(startGame, 2000);
  setTime();
};
```

...Then inside your `resetGame` function, you can set `gameOver = true` to stop the loop;